# Auto fit image on mobile and desktop with CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I havn't had any luck with this yet. We have a webpage where the images are successfully auto fitting on the mobile version but not on the desktop version. Please see attached the evidence on images and my php code. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

If there is any other infoarmation needed please let me know so I can update my post.

Note that the image name on the code is: rinconcriollo3.png. The one that is not autofitting. Don't pay attention to the rest of them as they are on different sizes.

```html
<div class="ps-4 ps-sm-4 ps-md-4 ps-lg-5 ps-xl-2 ps-xxl-0 pe-0 pe-sm-0 pe-md-4 pe-xl-4 pe-xxl-0 mb-3 mb-sm-0 mb-md-4 mb-lg-5 mb-xl-3 mb-xxl-0 mt-sm-2 mt-md-2 mt-lg-0 mt-xl-3 mt-xxl-0 pb-5 pb-sm-5 pb-md-5 pb-lg-3 pb-xl-2 pb-xxl-0 scale-iphone">
  <div class="card rounded-4 border-0 ms-0 ms-sm-0 ms-md-4 ms-lg-0 ms-xl-1 ms-xxl-1 me-4 me-sm-4 me-md-4 me-lg-4 me-xl-5 me-xxl-5 mb-3 bg-white shadow-lg card-scale-0">
    <div class="card-body p-2 mt-1">
      <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-4">
          <div class="">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NjZZJdMf/rinconcriollo3.png" class="img-fluid rounded-4" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 col-sm-8">
          <h6 class="mb-1"><a href="https://forms.gle/E4SBAeKfchyMvS6o6" target="_blank">Jefe de Cocina</a></h6>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <p class="mb-0 small">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days me-2 text-red"></i>Permanente
              </p>
              <p class="mb-0 small">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot me-2 text-red"></i><span class="fw-bold">Presencial</span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <p class="mb-0 small">
                <span class="text-red me-2">S/</span>1,450
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
```

Screenshots - click to enlarge

[image: Mobile version: Notice only the first image (red one)]
[image: Web version: not auto fitting]

Comment: There's _way_ too much code there. Almost 250 lines of HTML, and then we need to hunt for the CSS, download a bunch of libraries.  Please simplify this to a minimal amount of code that still has the problem. Also, although your site might be PHP-based, the render problem will only be CSS and HTML (and possibly JS if you are doing anything specific).

Comment: Are you using a framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 yes, using bootstrap. Would you like me to upload any other info?

Comment: Please add the Bootstrap tag to your question with the proper version

Comment: Done. Using Bootstrap v5.3.2

Comment: @Yogi, is there any additional information I can add to help find a way of auto scaling the image?

Comment: The only way I could make this work is by setting the rows to a fixed height and adding a max-height class to the images.  See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wcnfrq37/show) here.